# What are the conditions for the start coins in Mario Kart 8 multiplayer?

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

I played online a little in Mario Kart 8 and I noticed that my starting coins are different every time. Sometimes I start with 4, sometimes with 0. I believe in single player you start with 5 (at the 1st race of a grand prix), and every next race with 0.

I thought it had something to do with coins collected in the previous game, or with an excess amount (so collect coins while you have 10). I thought that because I had a very good race, much coins and a first place. The next race I started with 4 coins or something. But it proved false, because an other time, I sucked balls (actually I was very good, but the other players picked on me, and I got the wrong items, of course :P) and came in last with 0 coins. However, I started again with 4 coins.

So, what is going on with this starting coins madness?

*I say 4 starting coins in my whole question, and I only saw 0 or 4 in multiplayer. Not sure if that is actually the case or not*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of coins you start with is based on your position to start the race.

- 1st/2nd: 0
- 3rd/4th: 1
- 5th/6th: 2
- 7th/8th: 3
- 9th/10th: 4
- 11th/12th: 5

Comment: And is the position you start the race based on the previous race? Multiplayer that is, single player I know :)

Comment: Yep. You always start in whatever position you finished, with anyone in their first race at the end (so if people ahead of you quit, you move up).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. So I guess I was wrong when I finished first and started again with 4 coins :/